# How to augment the realm of functions Mathematica thinks it knows how to integrate symbolically

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, symbolic, assignment

> My question involves extending the functionality of `Integrate` over specific integrals in the most generic manner.

Specifically, is it possible to "hack into" `Integrate` so as a to add to the "grammar" of analytic integration a new family of integrals which the user would have provided (in the spirit of `ProbabilityDistribution` which allows the user to include his own PDF into the existing tools).

The idea is that Mathematica would be able to identify when such integrals pop up and replace it by the given definition. The specific example I have in mind involves the integral of `MultinormalDistribution` over square subregions of the integration domain. That is to say I would like to attach to either `MultiNormalDistribution`, or `Expectation`,  (or `Integrate`) the following rule

```
Expectation[Boole[(x>a)&&(y>b)], {x,y} ~Distributed~
    MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},{{1,c},{c,1}}]] = FF[a,b,c]
```

(where `FF` is a given function of `a`, `b`, and `c` which could be tabulated).

@JM suggested using  `TagSet` or `TagSetDelayed`, but the difficulty is to decide to which function it should be associated with, and with what efficiency, given that it would be unwise to temper with build in symbols like `Integrate`?

**Attempt**

As a simpler toy problem I tried

```
Unprotect[Integrate]; 
Integrate /: Integrate[f[x], {x, a_, b_}] = F[a, b] 
Protect[Integrate];
```

for which `Integrate[f[x],{x,1,2}]` returns `F[1,2]`

But for instance `Integrate[2 f[x], {x, 1, 2}]` is not evaluated, which suggests that my new (possibly admittedly dangerous) definition  has not been taken as a global rule for integration.

More relevantly, I tried

```
Unprotect[Expectation];
Expectation[ Boole[x_ > a_ && y_ > b_], {x_, y_}~Distributed~
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, c_}, {c_, 1}}]] = FF[a, b, c]
Protect[Expectation];
```

so that

```
Expectation[ 
 Boole[x > 1 && y > 2], {x, y}~Distributed~
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/3}, {1/3, 1}}]]
```

returns `FF[1,2,1/3]`

(after a short while).

**Questions**

1. What is the best way to write down the definition? Assign it to `MultinormalDistribution`, `Expectation`, `Integrate`?
2. How to make sure it is "integrated" by Mathematica so that when attempting, e.g. to compute the expectation of `d*Boole[x>a && y>b]` it would return `d*FF[a,b,c]` (or the expectation of `u+Boole[x>a && y>b]` the Expectation of `u + FF[a,b,c]`)? More specifically, how to make sure Mathematica tries to transform a given integral into a form which could match the new definition?

> UPDATE

The package [`Rubi4`](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) effectively extends the number of functions mathematica can integrate, though not following the path envisaged in this post.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Related: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Apr/msg00649.html

Comment: As it happens, the 2D example I give below has an "analytic" solution in terms of `OwenT` cf http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153421/does-the-integral-of-pdf-of-multi-normal-distribution-over-quarter-planes-have-a It remains interesting to extend it e.g. to 3D.

Comment: Dilapidating your fortune?

Comment: @belisarius very nouveau riche isn't it? I am actually really interested in the answer! (and what's the point being virtually rich :-)

Answer (score 12):

At first, overriding `Integrate[]` is not per-se dangerous. Nevertheless, you should make sure that it gives the correct results by implementing a few unit tests (for example check, that `Integrate[2 f[x], {x,1,2}]` truly results in `2F[1,2]`, as you'd expect.

Second, the pattern matching for `Integrate[]` is a bit more subtle: The rule you have given will not match `2 f[x]` as argument for integrate, but only functions depending on the integration variable *without* any prefactors.

A rule you could use for that purpose would be 
`Integrate[c_ f_[x_], {x_, a_, b_}] := c F[a, b] /; FreeQ[c, x]`, which checks whether `c` depends on `x`. You will also need a few other rules for multiplication, etc. It's important to note here that `c___` does not work as a pattern, as (schematically) `f[x]` is not the same as `(no prefactor) f[x]`.

Comment: If you change the pattern to include `c_. ` rather than `c_` you can capture more cases.