# Unprotect the Integrate command

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, customization

I entered the follow code in order to tell Mathematica an integral result, which it is unable to evaluate originally:

```
Unprotect[Integrate];
Integrate[Log[1-x]*Log[1+x]^2/x,{x,0,1}]:= -Pi^4/240
Protect[Integrate]
```

Then I entered

```
Integrate[Log[1-x]*Log[1+x]^2/x,{x,0,1}]
```

Mathematica gives the result I input, which is fine. However, when I tried

```
Integrate[1+Log[1-x]*Log[1+x]^2/x,{x,0,1}]
Integrate[2*Log[1-x]*Log[1+x]^2/x,{x,0,1}]
```

Mathematica return them unevaluated (as if I hadn't made that definition at all).

My question is, is it possible to make Mathematica more intelligent in this aspect? For my purpose, I would already be satisfied if Mathematica knows to use the following two properties:
$$\int f + \int g = \int(f+g) \qquad \int (cf) = c\int f$$
that is, whenever I defined the value of $\int f, \int g$, Mathematica can return $\int(f+g)$. My scope of integration will be solely single variable definite with exact arithmetic.

Thank you very much.

Comment: MMA(11.0.1.0) evaluates `Integrate[Log[1 - x] Log[1 + x]^2/x, {x, 0, 1}]==0` which is obviously wrong???

Comment: I understand that this comment does not address the question directly, but if you *know* the 'values'/formulas of $\int f, \int g$, then why would you want to calculate $\int f+g$ / $\int c f$ instead of performing the addition/multiplication directly?

Comment: @user42582  The background is that I have several integral results $\int f_1, \int f_2 ,\cdots, \int f_n$ which Mathematica is unable to find out. However, their expression are all quite long, and I have to evaluate a bunch of integrals that are linear combinations of $f_i$ and other functions whose integral that Mathematica can originally calculate. Therefore it would be great if I could feed these integral results into Mathematica directly.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am using an older version of Mathematica, here it returns it unevaluated. But the integral is obviously nonzero, as seen by numerical integration. Probably a bug?

Comment: @pisco125 : Probably yes

Comment: @UlrichNeumann *Mathematica* 9.0, 10.3 and 11.2 return unevaluated.  *Mathematica* 8.0, 10.4, 11.0, and 11.1 (incorrectly) returns `0`.  Very interesting history...

Comment: The linearity properties you would like *Mathematica* to use are not generally valid, unless you can prove that the integrals are convergent.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(6169)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6169); also related: [(19534)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19534), [(118938)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118938)

Comment: 11.2 returns unevaluated if evaluated after starting Mathematica and 0 on subsequent evals (even after quitting and restarting the kernel)

Comment: Another related Q&A: [(64422)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64422)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a more general rule to do your integral:

```
Unprotect[Integrate];
Integrate[a_. + b_. Log[1 - x]*Log[1 + x]^2/x, {x, 0, 1}] /; FreeQ[b, x] := 
  Integrate[a, {x, 0, 1}] - b Pi^4/240;
Protect[Integrate];
```

Then your examples work as intended:

```
Integrate[1+Log[1-x]*Log[1+x]^2/x,{x,0,1}]
Integrate[2*Log[1-x]*Log[1+x]^2/x,{x,0,1}]
```

> ```
> 1-π^4/240
>
> -π^4/120
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`Unprotect`-ing sounds scary.

This answer is trying to address the following (text in braces is added)

> "... I would already be satisfied if Mathematica knows to use the following two properties:  [*reversing addition and scalar multiplication for integrals*]"

I am not sure if this is helpful, but you can define something like a linear operator that displays the behavior described in the question (and relevant comments):

```
Plus[int[f_, x_], int[g_, x_]] ^:= int[f + g, x]
Times[a_, int[f_, x_]] ^:= int[a f, x] /; FreeQ[a, x]
```

Assuming it is possible to replace all expressions like `Log[1 - x] Log[1 + x]^2/x` with appropriate symbols (eg `Log[1 - x] Log[1 + x]^2/x->f1` etc) then evaluating eg a variation of the expressions in the question

```
int[1+f1,x] + int[2f1,x]
```

returns

```
int[1+3f1,x]
```

Effectively, what this answer proposes is to use the `int` operator in order to gather all the integrals that would otherwise not evaluate, in an expression  of the form `int[a1 f1+a2 f2+...an fn,x]`.

What is supposed to happen from then on is not clear to me.