How to add a custom analytical integration to integration library
How can I add an unknown analytical integral in Mathematica to its integration library so that the Integrate routine, e.g.  Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], outputs g[x], which is the solution of an integral table?

You could check this question/answer overriding-a-built-in-function-with-custom-coded-procedures

Duplicates:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/how-to-augment-the-realm-of-functions-mathematica-thinks-it-knows-how-to-integra
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19534/is-there-a-way-to-teach-integrate-new-solutions

First, 'Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` is a definite integral and does return not a function, but a value.
However, perhaps you mean: 'Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}]' the returns a function of y: g[y]. For this you can write:
Unprotect[Integrate];
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, y_}] = g[y];
Protect[Integrate];

Now you get the function g if you write:
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, w}]

g[w]


I don' think this is really a feasible solution ... As soon as you do Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, w}], the code doesn't work anymore. So you just defined one particular downvalue to Integrate, but didn't really properly include this to the "integration tables", so to speak.
