# MacDonald formula for Modified Bessel Functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

How can I make Mathematica understand these two integrals?

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh{\xi}} d\xi = K_0(x)$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{x y}{u} + u \frac{x^2+y^2}{x y} \Big) } K_{i t}(u) \frac{du}{u} = K_{i t}(x) K_{i t}(y) $$

There is some discussion about the first form in this question: [(4728) incorrect intergrate results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/incorrect-results-for-elementary-integrals-when-using-integrate). I've run across the second form in the literature under the name "MacDonald identity."

Stating explicitly that all variables are real and positive does not seem to help `Integrate` evaluate these forms. Is there something else I can do to help *Mathematica* concerning these integrals? I have some experience working with integrals related to modified Bessel functions, but I'm at a loss here. Any tips for success with these forms or other things to try are appreciated.

Comment: you could up vote this question (:-)) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/how-to-augment-the-realm-of-functions-mathematica-thinks-it-knows-how-to-integra

Comment: "Integrate`InverseIntegrate[Exp[-x Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity},  Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]"

Comment: @belisarius Yes I saw this 'experimental' command in the other question.I actually assumed that experimental meant it wasn't in the retail version. It does not find the answer to the second integral I posted.