# Probability of multivariate normal being positive on each coordinate

Tags: probability-or-statistics, special-functions

How can I find the probability that each coordinate of a specified multivariate normal distribution is positive? I tried the following, which I believed should work

```
mu = {0, 0, 0};
sigma = {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}};
Probability[
 x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
 MultinormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]
```

Unfortunately, for the output I just get the last line from the input (with mu and sigma replaced by their actual values).  I don't see where the problem could possibly be since the matrix is positive definite. If I replace it by the identity matrix everything works fine (i.e. the output is 1/8).

Comment: possibly related? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6169/1089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general integral does not have a closed form solution, so use `NIntegrate`:

```
mu = {0, 0, 0};
    sigma = {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}};
    NIntegrate[
     PDF[MultinormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {x, y, z}],
     {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}, {z, 0, ∞}]
```

(* 0.25 *)

Check:

```
mu = {0, 0, 0};
sigma2 = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
NIntegrate[
 PDF[MultinormalDistribution[mu, sigma2], {x, y, z}],
 {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}, {z, 0, ∞}]
```

(* 0.125 *)

Note that symbolic integration and symbolic probability work for the two-dimensional version of this problem:

```
mu = {0, 0};
sigma = {{2, 1}, {1, 2}};
Probability[x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]
```

and

```
Integrate[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {x, y}], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}]
```

yield the answer

(* 1/3 *)

Comment: An even simpler way is to replace `Probability` with `NProbability` (adds one additional character to the OP's code).

Comment: Yep...  Simpler.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much

Comment: The general integral for the OPs $n=3$ case does actually have a closed-form solution: posted below.

Answer (score 9):

The probability that the OP seeks is known as the multivariate Normal orthant probability. Correctly, for the $n=3$ cased posed here, the general integral DOES in fact have a closed -form solution, though Mma cannot (currently) obtain it.

In particular, given a zero mean vector and variance-covariance matrix:

$$\Sigma =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \rho _{\text{xy}} & \rho _{\text{xz}} \\
 \rho _{\text{xy}} & 1 & \rho _{\text{yz}} \\
 \rho _{\text{xz}} & \rho _{\text{yz}} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$\dots$ the standardised trivariate Normal orthant probability is:

$$P(X>0,Y>0,Z>0)  \quad = \quad \frac{1}{8} + \frac{\text{ArcSin}\left[\rho _{\text{xy}}\right]+ \text{ArcSin}\left[\rho _{\text{xz}}\right]+ \text{ArcSin}\left[\rho _{\text{yz}}\right]}{4 \pi }$$

For application and more detail, see, for instance:

- Chapter 6 of our book:   Rose and Smith, *Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica* (Section 6.4C) $\rightarrow$ a free download is available at: http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html , or
- Stuart and Ord (1994), *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics* (6th edition): section 15.10 and 15.11.

**Example**

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ have a standardised multivariate Normal with zero mean vector, and variance covariance matrix:

```
sigma = {{1, 27/34, 22/23}, {27/34, 1, 4/5}, {22/23, 4/5, 1}}
```

Then, the exact orthant probability is given immediately as:

```
P3 = 1/8 + (ArcSin[27/34] + ArcSin[22/23] + ArcSin[4/5])/(4 Pi)
```

... which, to 10 decimal places, is:

```
N[P3, 10] 
0.3732564868
```

By contrast, the approach using numerical integration can be unreliable here:

```
NIntegrate[ PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, sigma], {x, y, z}], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}, {z, 0, Infinity}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly ...
>
> 0.371907

Numerical integration can sometimes be awkward, unreliable, or slow (as in this example) ... and having an exact closed-form instantaneous solution is a better way to proceed, if possible.

**From general to standardised**

Given a zero mean vector, what if our variance-covariance matrix is not in a standardised form (with 1's along the main diagonal)? We can easily convert it into standardised form. If, say, our variance-covariance matrix is:

```
  sigma = {{3, 1/3, 3/2}, {1/3, 2/3, -1}, {3/2, -1, 4}}
```

... then the standardised variance-covariance matrix `S` is:

```
 A = DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[sigma]^(-(1/2))];
 S = A.sigma.A
```

All done.

Comment: I eagerly looked up your book because I wanted to see "more detail"... but there isn't any more detail, just a restatement of the same formula and a reference to Stuart and Ord's book.

Comment: The book also gives the closed-form solution for the bivariate case, and then uses these exact formulae as benchmarks to check the performance/accuracy of Mma's numerical integration routines. In case you are about to eagerly consult Stuart and Ord, I should perhaps caution that you won't find very much more detail there either for the $n=2$ or 3 cases as to results (though more as to derivation)... but they do also provide useful references for higher dimensions.

Comment: Not quite all done.  Let's help the OP by giving him the closed form solution for his particular covariance matrix.

Comment: @Rahul I believe the result can be obtained by a linear change of variables that diagonalizes and normalizes the quadratic form of the pdf (to `Exp[k (u^2+v^2+w^2)]`). The orthant is transformed to a domain that is subtended by a spherical triangle with angles $\pi/2+ \sin^{-1}\rho$, where $\rho$ runs over the nondiagonal coefficients of $\Sigma$. The result is the proportion of the sphere that is cut out (by the symmetry of the integral). A similar result is true for $n=2$.